# Git push new repo based on other repo, start new

Tags: node.js, git, github, package.json

I clone git project(MIT) and made some changes in this project update the **package.json** (name and remove un-neccery things ).

Now when I commit it to my own repo I get the the old package.json 
with list of all contributors commits etc, I want it to start from 
scratch for example that my pust will be the first commit, how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of the `.git` directory. I assume you are using Bash so you could (in the project directory) remove that with `rm -rf .git` and just `git init` to initialize your own Git history.

Then you could add all the files again `git add --all` and `git commit -m 'Initial commit'`. Then just add your own repository as origin with `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git`.

Your history would now be clean with your own initial commit.